# how to link the pages using codeigniter pagination?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

how to link the pages using codeigniter pagination?

the problem is with the variable $start its supposed to pass the start value to the database limit query . but its not.

Model

```
public function fetch_countries($limit,$start) {
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);

    //$query ="SELECT * FROM  mail_to Order By id Desc LIMIT ".$limit.",".$start;
    $query = $this->db->get("mail_to");

   //$qry=$this->db->query($query);
   var_dump($query->result_array());

    if($query->num_rows()>0){

       return $query->result_array();

    }
    else
    {
    return false;
}

}
```

Controller

```
public function example1() {
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/admin/user/example1";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->mdl_user->record_count();
    $config["per_page"] = 5;

    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);




    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

    //var_dump($config['per_page']);
    $data["results"] = $this->mdl_user->fetch_countries($config["per_page"],$page);
        //var_dump($data['results']);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->load->view("example1", $data);
}
```

Comment: thanks man. it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URI Segment should be

```
$config["uri_segment"] = 4;
$page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
```

**In Model**

```
public function fetch_countries($limit, $page)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM mail_to LIMIT $page, $limit");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result; 
}
```

**In Controller**

```
public function example1() {

    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/admin/user/example1";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->mdl_user->record_count();
    $config["per_page"] = 5;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
    $limit = $config['per_page'];
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;

    $data["results"] = $this->mdl_user->fetch_countries($page $limit);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->load->view("example1", $data);
}
```

Comment: i have worte the tutorial about Codeigniter Pagination. https://www.cloudways.com/blog/pagination-in-codeigniter/. Have a look and give your suggestions